# Unity Android build Bad Performance but IOS is ok

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I'm making a mobile game and have some troubles with Android.
On IOS game works perfect, 60fps, very fast scene loading 1-2 sec.
On Android First scene is loading like 5-6 min(Menu Scene), game scenes seems like infinite loading.
I testet On Xiaomi phones, Pixel and Galaxy. Everywhere is the same problem.

I left one scene in the game, it loads instantly, but as I add more scenes the game takes longer and longer to load with each scene.
Its seems like game is loading all the scenes at once.

Could someone please help me I'm stuck with this.

This is the code on first scene :

string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Data23.fun";

```
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            if (PSM.CharacterCreated)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
            }
            else
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Save File not exist in Path : " + path);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
```

Comment: Do you using maybe a lot of FindObjectOfType or by tag in awake? try to use more reference using [SerializeField] becuase it can be really heavy.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply, no I'm not using FindObjectOfType, is just one script who is checking if player is created and loads the next scene. I tried to delete all scene and left only menu scene and it works fine, but when I add more scenes like game scenes is loading very long. And I have this problem only on Android.

Comment: Can you please share your script? It can be helpful to understand why it's happen

Comment: The all loadings in game are very long, even an empty scene. I tried to use LoadSceneAsync and LoadScene. Both have the same loading time.

Comment: it's really hard to read it here, please edit your question with the code properly

Comment: I did another test and left one scene in the game, it loads instantly, but as I add more scenes the game takes longer and longer to load with each scene. Its seems like game is loading all the scenes at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem was wrong "Base Gradle Template" settings.